# Localhost development with cookies

Tags: cookies

I have a google cloud bucket CDN-Cookie to access my google cloud bucket pictures. On my web server everything is working great with setting the cookies and retrieving the image. But in my development environment, I'm on localhost and it's not sending the cookies because it doesn't have https. What's the go-to approach for a development environment to deal with this kind of issue as making localhost to https://localhost seems quite complex for multiple development environments.

**Here the http://localhost cookie error**

> Migrate entirely to HTTPS to have cookies sent to same-site
> subresources A cookie was not sent to a secure origin from an insecure
> context. Because this cookie would have been sent across schemes on
> the same site, it was not sent. This behavior enhances the SameSite
> attribute’s protection of user data from request forgery by network
> attackers. Resolve this issue by migrating your site (as defined by
> the eTLD+1) entirely to HTTPS. It is also recommended to mark the
> cookie with the Secure attribute if that is not already the case.

Answer (score 4):

To start, it sounds like your localhost development workflow includes some portions on https, otherwise you wouldn't be seeing that message: "A cookie was not sent to a **secure origin** from an insecure context".

> What's the go-to approach for a development environment to deal with this kind of issue

There's not one per-se, it's dependent on your environment.
You have a few options that you can consider:

1. Upgrade entirely to https. You mentioned that this is complicated for your setup, so this one probably won't suit you (maybe https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/ helps?).
2. Downgrade entirely to http during localhost development. This error only appears because you're trying to send cookies across different schemes, if everything is http then you won't experience it.
3. Change `SameSite=Strict` and `SameSite=Lax` cookies to `SameSite=None; Secure`. Samesite=None cookies are sent freely between schemes.
4. Disable Schemeful Same-Site via chrome://flags/#schemeful-same-site. This will be going away in the coming months so I don't recommend relying on it.
5. Enable legacy cookies features through [LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled) or [LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList) enterprise policies. This option is also temporary so, again, best not to rely on it. Also this does a bit more such as removing the "`SameSite=None` must be `Secure` requirement" and "Unspecified SameSite is treated as `SameSite=Lax`", see the links for more info there.

Comment: thank you for your well thought answer. To 1. : Yes I've seen this link thank you for adding it here. 2.: I don't think this is an option as far as I remember I needed to upgrade from http to https to make cookies authentication with buckets possible in first place. 3. I'm on it and adding that information to my cookies, SameSite wasn't set yet. What do you mean by setting SameSite and SameSite to None as this is the same key. Also there is a format mistake at 2. at "Secure" what do you want me to set Secure to? Thanks for now.

Comment: "What do you mean by setting SameSite and SameSite to None"
I called out `SameSite=Strict` and `SameSite=Lax` to mean that any cookies with _either_ attribute value should be changed to be `SameSite=None; Secure`.

"SameSite wasn't set yet"
In that case your cookies were being handled as if they had set `SameSite=Lax`. See [here](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/) if you're unfamiliar with SameSite.

"Also there is a format mistake at 2. at "Secure" what do you want me to set Secure to?"
You don't need to supply a value for `Secure` you just need to include the attribute.

Comment: Weird, as soon as I change the code to change the cookies. It's no longer setting the cookie. My code as follows.            ```resp = Response({}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers={
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': '*',
                'Set-Cookie': 'Cloud-CDN-Cookie=' + cookie + '; Domain=domain.com; Path=/; Expires=' + formatted_date + '; SameSite=None; Secure',
            })``` again that you for your help

Comment: Chrome's DevTools will tell you why a cookie was rejected so I recommend checking there. If I had to guess however I would suspect the new usage of `Secure` is causing the problem; the connection that is attempting to set the cookie must be secure (https) or from localhost.

Comment: I was inspecting that further and yes, as soon as I set it this way it says: This cookie was blocked because it had the "Secure" attribute but was not received over a secure connection. Hm so seems like 3 is not working. To 4. I tried that already before posting here but it seemed like it had no effect.

Comment: It's sadly getting worse. Now after got my React frontend to work with https: I can no longer access my backend as it is Django and also served locally for development. So therefore I can't even log in to check if https: fixed my google cloud access for local development.

Comment: First: What do you mean that #4 (disable Schemeful Same-Site) no effect? That should resolve your original problem and I'm curious if it did not. Second: Another option you have (rather than trying to upgrade all your dependencies to https) is to tell Chrome to treat those origins as if they were secure via chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure. This will allow you to set `Secure` cookies from an http connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i was working on a MERN application where my node js was having a HTTPS server but in developement the frontend react was running on http so the cookies were not getting sent in the request header. Adding following in express-session code solved the issue

```js
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: "auto",
    },
  })
);
```